# Material Design lite dialog render in Safari desktop and phone

Tags: javascript, html, safari, mobile-safari, material-design-lite

I have followed [getmdl.io](https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#dialog-section)'s example to implement a `dialog` component. It works fine in Chrome, Firefox and Android Web views; but in Safari, it renders `dialog` elements even if they are not invoked. I have put the example at the end of body element just before script elements.

[image]

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Material Design Lite uses the [dialog-Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog), which is not supported by all browsers. (See [Browser-Compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#search=dialog))

> This is an experimental technology Because this technology's
>   specification has not stabilized, check the compatibility table for
>   usage in various browsers. Also note that the syntax and behavior of
>   an experimental technology is subject to change in future versions of
>   browsers as the specification changes.

To make it work in other browsers, you have to include the [dialog-polyfill](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/dialog-polyfill). Also please note, that `<dialog>`-Elements should be located directly after the `<body>`-tag and not inside any other wrappers.

See codesample copied from dialog-polyfill:

```
<head>
  <script src="dialog-polyfill.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dialog-polyfill.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <dialog>
    I'm a dialog!
    <form method="dialog">
      <input type="submit" value="Close" />
    </form>
  </dialog>
  <script>
    var dialog = document.querySelector('dialog');
    dialogPolyfill.registerDialog(dialog);
    // Now dialog acts like a native <dialog>.
    dialog.showModal();
  </script>
</body>
```

Also the Dialog-Element will be removed from HTML 5.1, since chrome is the only browser that actually supports it natively. See https://github.com/w3c/html/issues/427

Comment: Thanks! This was the exact case.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, glad to help!